# MVC mismatch between controller output and View properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a very simple EF (CodeFirst) structure in my MVC4 app.

In my controller I have this simple query:

```
var activity = db.Activities.Where(a => a.Engagement.Id == Id);
```

My view can handle the results of this query with no problem.

However, I need to join a table to my activities table when I make the query.  This query works for me:

```
var activity = from a in db.Activities
                       join m in db.Members on a.MemberID equals m.Id
                       where a.Engagement.Id == Id
                       select new
                       {
                           a.Description,
                           a.ActivityDate,
                           a.EngagementStageValue,
                           a.Hours,
                           m.Email,
                       };
```

The problem is the view cannot interpret the result of the query.  I get this error:

"*The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`5[System.String,System.DateTime,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DomainClasses.Activity]'."*

I am relatively new to MVC and EF (nasty learning curve), any help would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a ActivityModel class that will have properties you need so:

```
public class ActivityModel
{
  public string Description {get; set;}
  public DateTime ActivityDate {get; set;}
  public yourtype EngagementStageValue {get; set;}
  public DateTime Hours {get; set;}
  public string Email {get; set;}

  //you can also add new properties to get a cleaner view for an example
  public string ActivityDateShort{ 

      get{
            return ActivityDate.ToShortDateString();
         }

}

var activity = (from a in db.Activities
                       join m in db.Members on a.MemberID equals m.Id
                       where a.Engagement.Id == Id
                       select new ActivityModel
                       {
                          Description = a.Description,
                          ActivityDate = a.ActivityDate,
                          EngagementStageValue = a.EngagementStageValue,
                          Hours = a.Hours,
                          Email = m.Email,
                       }).ToList();
```

so you will get an List and pass this to your view as model and do what you like with it. Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are generating an anonymous type and that view is strongly typed.  Basically, you have created a new type when you added the 'Email' field and the view doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that.  Is there a work around? How can I modify the view to accommodate the additional property?

Comment: Typically I would create a ViewModel that adds the additional field.  In your case, it would end up being a collection of ViewModels.  There is probably a smarter way though.